# Windows Firewall + FTP Server on WS03

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2003

my OS is Windows Server 2003.
I installed the FTP Service and configure it with the IIS 6.0 Console.
When I deactivate my firewall, all its okay, but when not, I can't get a connection.
Port 21 tcp + udp, port 22 tcp + udp and the whole FTP-Server Application is set as go trouhgt, but don't work. Of course, the FTP ruins on 21.

Any ideas

Comment: Ports 21 and 22? Better make that 20 and 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Server 2003, if you are running FTP as `C:\ftp localhost`, that should work as FTP will be accessed over 127.0.0.1 and that does not require any exception. But if you are accessing `C:\ftp ip_address`, you will be able to login but as soon as you fire `dir` or `ls`, you will be prompted by **Windows Security Alert** to add **FTP** in Unblocked or Blocked list. **Unblock FTP Service** and you should be fine.

Now, if you go to Control Panel -> Windows Firewall and click on Exception. You will find File Transfer Protocol checked i.e. now FTP is unblocked through the firewall.

You can also use netsh command as shown below to verify if FTP is in allowedprogram list.

```
netsh firewall>show allowedprogram

Allowed programs configuration for Domain profile:
Mode     Name / Program
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Enable   File Transfer Program / C:\WINDOWS\system32\ftp.exe
```